# How to use fscanf to read doubles in C

Tags: c, scanf

I am currently writing a program that takes in an unknown number of doubles, each on their own line from a text file. It should be placing of these elements read into an array, but it isn't working. My print loop works, but it only prints zeroes. I've tried a lot of things and looked up a lot before coming here. This is my code.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    //Open an file to read from
    FILE *file;
    file = fopen("data.txt","r");
    if (file == NULL)
    {
        printf("File not found.");
        return -1;
    }

    //Count the number of lines in the input file
    int numLines = 0; //CHANGE TO 1 ???
    int ch;
    do
    {
        ch = fgetc(file);
        if (ch == '\n')
            numLines++;
    } while (ch != EOF);

    //Put all of the data read into an array;
    double input[numLines];
    int i = 0;
    while ((fscanf(file, "%lf\n", &input[i])) == 1)
        i++;

    //Close the file
    fclose(file);

    //Test printing elements of array
    for (i = 0; i < numLines; i++)
        printf("%lf\n", input[i]);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You need to [`rewind`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/rewind) the file pointer after you have counted the lines, otherwise you are still at the end of the file when you try to read the actual input data.

Comment: You want to use a format like `" %lf"` (not `"%lf\n"`) in order to skip any leading whitespace, not any trailing.

Comment: You only need to do `printf("%f\n", input[i]);`  The `l` doesn't have any impact, since there's for printf format specifier for floats, which would be automatically promoted to doubles.

Comment: That worked. Thank you.

Comment: @Jens For this code `"%lf"`, `" %lf"`, `"%lf\n"`, `" %lf\n"` all work equally well.  `"%lf"` is simplest.

Comment: @EdgyCoder If the last line does not end in a `'\n'`, `double input[numLines];` will be too small.  Increase by 1 and use the last `i` from `while ((fscanf(file, "%lf\n", &input[i])) == 1)
        i++;`, not `numLines`, as the number of `input[]` to print.

Answer (score 1):

OP's test of `fscanf()` result is *good*, except code did not also check if too many numbers were in the file.

```
while ((fscanf(file, "%lf\n", &input[i])) == 1)
    i++;
```

Then code ignored that last value of `i` and instead printed `numLines` times, even if fewer were successfully scanned.

```
for (i = 0; i < numLines; i++)
    printf("%lf\n", input[i]);
```

End code should have been

```
while (i < numLines && (fscanf(file, "%lf\n", &input[i])) == 1)
    i++;
for (j = 0; j < i; j++)
    printf("%lf\n", input[j]);
```

This would have printed 0 lines! The file needed to be reset for a second pass. [@paulr](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43286609/how-to-use-fscanf-to-read-doubles-in-c#comment73641414_43286609)

```
rewind(file);
while (i < numLines && (fscanf(file, "%lf\n", &input[i])) == 1)
  ...
```

A further problem is assuming the count of `'\n'` is the same as the count of numbers.  This can easily be fooled given multiple numbers per line or the last line having a number yet no `'\n'`.

A simple work-around it to make the `input[]` 1 larger and use the actual scan success count as the count of numbers to print.  More robust code would read 1 line at a time with `fgets()` and include additional error checks.